# LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090446, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580 - using Spring tools

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, ldap

Hello I am using the following code to authenticate an application in spring tools which is hosted on a Tomcat.

This is the code I am running:

```
package com.pp.portal;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
          .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
          .formLogin();
      }

      @Override
      public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          File jks = File.createTempFile("cacerts", "jks");
            jks.deleteOnExit();
            
            try (InputStream fromJks = WebSecurityConfig.class.getResource("/cacerts.jks").openStream()) {
                FileCopyUtils.copy(FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(fromJks), jks);
            }
     
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", jks.getPath());
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
          
            auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
                .userSearchFilter("&(sAMAccountName={0})(memberOf=CN=SG_LoginHistoryApp_Operators,OU=Security*Groups*-*NEW,OU=Secured*Groups,OU=Administration,DC=Domain,DC=uk,DC=dc)")
                .contextSource()
                    .url("ldaps://ldapserver.domain.uk.dc:636")
                    .managerDn("CN=ldap,OU=Accounts,OU=Users,OU=Adapt,DC=Domain,DC=uk,DC=dc")
                    .managerPassword("mangerPassword"); 

      }
     

}
```

This is the error I am getting back:

```
[LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090446, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090446, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580]
```

I am looking for suggestions on how to remedy this, credentials used are correct for both, user I am using to log in and account being used.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and error code.

In my case the password for the user was no more valid. There is an option that the passwords invalidate after x days. Did you check that?